# How to Customize jCountdown timer which is using css sprite resources to become auto Responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, countdowntimer

The jCountdown plugin has good effect.
https://0.s3.envato.com/files/42592367/index.html

However by Inspecting the resources, it seems like the plugin is using css sprite animation to achieve the effect. wondering how difficult it would be to make it become 
responsive/albe to view without seeing horizontal overflow-x scroll bar
on small dimensions that is < 485px.

I'll be using "slide" effect so below img is slide_black skin.
maybe can share some tips on customizing script / css / or photoshop the image to create diff dimensions to fit responsive.

[image]

using the width option is one option to do but I think the pitfall is that result would be blur especially for the day/hour/min/sec label picture text

```
$("#timer").jCountdown({
             timeText:  tdate,                        
             timeZone: 8,
             style: "slide",
             color: "black",
             width: 225,
             textGroupSpace: 15,
             textSpace: 0,
             reflection: !1,
             reflectionOpacity: 10,
             reflectionBlur: 0,
             dayTextNumber: 2,
             displayDay: !0,
             displayHour: !0,
             displayMinute: !0,
             displaySecond: !0,
             displayLabel: !0,
             onFinish: function() {}
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this playing with `transform:scale()` property, adding some jQuery to find the correct scale value  and applying it. Exemple :

```
var value = yourOwnRatioCalculDependingOnClosestResponsiveParent;
$('.jCountdownContainer').css({
    "-moz-transform"    : "scale("+value+")",
    "-webkit-transform" : "scale("+value+")",
    "-ms-transform"     : "scale("+value+")",
    "-o-transform"      : "scale("+value+")",
    "transform"         : "scale("+value+")",
});
```

As you can see inspecting this plugin, adding a css scale to `.jCountdownContainer` works fine (with Chrome Dev Tool for exemple).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, comparing to edit image , this is a very efficient way to handle it.

Comment: Pleasure ;) Sure, working directly on the image should be such a hard task ! But maybe it would be possible adding a short fix for the size/position into the js.